# If salvation in Christ is not lessened without the perpetual virginity of Mary why must one believe the Dogma or be lost?

Tags: catholicism, soteriology, dogma

> No one who knowingly and deliberately rejects the truth will be saved. It doesn’t matter how good of a Muslim, Jew, Baptist, or anything else he may be. If anyone rejects the truth of Christ and his Church—**even one definitive teaching**—they will be lost. - [Catholic Answers](https://www.catholic.com/magazine/online-edition/is-there-really-no-salvation-outside-the-catholic-church)

This is summary point #1 in a Roman Catholic article explaining *extra ecclesiam nulla salus* which is an infallible statement meaning 'outside the Church there is no salvation'.  The article talks, in part, about '[invincible ignorance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invincible_ignorance_(Catholic_theology))' regarding not just commission of material sins but also of salvific truth:

> “Those who, through no fault of their own, do not know the Gospel of Christ or his Church, but who nevertheless seek God with a sincere heart, and, moved by grace, try in their actions to do his will as they know it through the dictates of their conscience – those too may achieve eternal salvation” (quoting, Lumen Gentium, 16).

*Note:  The article uses the terms 'Catholic Church' and 'Catholic Faith' frequently and reading it one assumes 'Roman Catholic' is intended rather than the older definition of catholic as 'universal'.  Likewise, when 'Church' is used the assumption is that Roman Catholic Church is intended. If I am wrong in this assumption and Roman Catholic Church is not intended, please correct me in comments as it will drastically change and perhaps even invalidate this question.

The article lays out that anyone who is knowledgeable of and in rejection of "even one definitive teaching" of Christ's Church will be lost.  They will not be saved unless they repent and accept that teaching that they have previously rejected.

I have always understood the 4 Marian Dogmas to be necessarily believed in order to be a member in good standing of the Roman Catholic Church:

> Through the authority of His Church on earth, God has revealed to us four essential truths about Mary’s identity, otherwise known as “the Marian dogmas.”  To be in full communion with Christ—the Church reminds us—we must believe in each of these dogmas. In other words, they aren’t optional beliefs. - [Good Catholic](https://www.goodcatholic.com/what-are-the-four-marian-dogmas/)

But now, knowing that these Marian Dogmas are definitive, infallible teachings of the RCC and putting them in combination with the first quote (above), it appears that anyone who knowingly and deliberately rejects even one Marian Dogma will be lost.  In other words, any member of any Protestant denomination or Church whatsoever who has what the RCC considers to be [valid baptism](https://www.dosp.org/wp-content/uploads/9_3.-Valid-and-Invalid-Baptisms.pdf) and [marriage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marriage_in_the_Catholic_Church) sacraments are still completely and hopelessly lost if they knowingly and deliberately reject say, the 'Perpetual Virginity of Mary' for example.

A Roman Catholic [answer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/75063/47250) to a a previous question clearly stated that the perpetual virginity of Mary bestows no salvific benefit:

> Even without the perpetual virginity of Mary, our salvation in Christ not lessened! Christ would still be Our Redeemer and Mary would still be the Mother of Jesus, the Church founded by Christ, and all mankind. However, it would be seen through the eyes of the Church in a totally different perspective!

Perhaps for a Roman Catholic the perpetual virginity of Mary adds a depth of understanding to the entire plan of salvation, the nature of God, etc., and that is fine, but it seems a contradiction to declare that a person will be lost unless they believe a doctrine that has no salvific benefit.

My question is:  If salvation in Christ is not lessened without the perpetual virginity of Mary why must one believe the Dogma or be lost?

Comment: To reject an article of the faith is not that same as to be invincibly ignorant of it. Her perpetual virginity is not an optional "added extra" but part of Christ's salvific plan. You need to focus on one question at a time, establishing whether "salvation in Christ is not lessened without the perpetual virginity of Mary" first (which seems akin to asking whether "salvation in Christ is not lessened without the" Incarnation, Resurrection, or any other christological dogma).

Comment: Up-voted +1. I am mystified by the claim that anything Mary did after bringing forth Jesus, could affect the salvation of others, since that salvation is dependent solely on Christ himself, and none other. Good question.

Comment: In the article, he says 'lost' but never defines what he means. He then later says, in regards to culpability, 'we don’t [AKSHUALLY] know' and also mentions 'extraordinary' means of salvation as an alternative. So the 'must' is at least to some degree hedged here.

Comment: @Geremia It is categorically stated in the Catholic answer (that I linked) that "Even without the perpetual virginity of Mary, our salvation in Christ not lessened!"  Why do I need to establish what has been stated?

Comment: @MikeBorden [Another answer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/94195/1787) to that question "categorically" states the contrary.

Comment: I am not too sure if the **Catholic Answer** quotation has an imprimatur. This needs clarification, for example, a Catholic who publicly and obstinately denies the perpetual virginity of Mary, would incur a latae sententiae excommunication based on Can. 1364 §1, since that is a dogma that must be believed with divine and catholic faith. Of course, that does not mean that the person will be automatically condemned (a common misconception; after all, he may be acting in good faith, albeit mistakenly). However, before receiving the sacraments again he would have to have his censure lifted.

Comment: Another point of clarification: The term Catholic Church refers to just that. It is not to be inferred to as Roman Catholic understanding but as a Catholic teaching. Although defined by the Church, it teachings are for the Universal Church, that is to say the Latin Rite and all Eastern Catholic Rite united to under the leadership of the pope.

Comment: @KenGraham According to this answer (https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/52738/47250) Pope Pious XII says it is a mortal sin to deny the Assumption.  "¶45 of Munificentissimus Deus makes it clear that those why deny the Assumption incur the highest theological censure: heresy. This is a "Mortal sin committed directly against the virtue of faith, and, if the heresy is outwardly professed, excommunication is automatically incurred and membership of the Church forfeited."  If it is a mortal sin to deny one of the Marian Dogmas it must be so for the others as well.

Comment: @KenGraham Therefore Protestants may have a valid Baptism but in Catholic eyes they are guilty of ongoing, unrepentant mortal sin over something that adds nothing to the salvation Christ has purchased.  Their 'valid Baptism' avails them nothing so long as they deny the Marian Dogmas.  They are, as Catholic Answers asserts, lost.

Comment: Again I say it seems that Catholic Answers lack an imprimatur. Catholic dogma is for Catholics, not non-Catholics. That excludes Jews, Muslims and other non-Catholic Christians.

Comment: @KenGraham But if their answers line up with Catholic teaching, what does that matter?  You don't have an imprimatur for your answers here, do you? Munificentissimus Deus says denying the Assumption is a mortal sin, which renders a person lost unless repented.  I cannot find an exactly similar statement regarding perpetual virginity but, as both are Dogmas and absolutely required beliefs, the result of denial must be the same.  Hence Catholic Answers says denying **even one definitive teaching** renders one lost.  They are simply affirming what Pope Pious XII infallibly pronounced.

Comment: If you say that you only have to believe in what adds salvific benefit, you are equivalently saying that revelation has only instrumental value towards my salvation or in other words it's "what's in it for me to believe this?"

Comment: @eques Salvation has intrinsic value because it is true.  The instrumental value of  any belief is whether or not it lines up with truth.  Therefore it is not "my belief" in Christ that saves me but Christ Himself who has (intrinsically) saved me and I enter in (instrumentally) through faith.  If a definitive teaching adds nothing to the intrinsic value of salvation then there is no ground to require belief in that teaching as necessary for salvation.  Christ's salvation of you is the same if Mary is not a perpetual virgin.

Comment: @eques You are perfectly free to believe it as long as it does not detract from salvation in Christ.  My contention is that requiring belief in it as a "definitive teaching" or else one is lost is just such a detraction.

Comment: @MikeBorden You are correct that salvation relates to truth and that the value of any belief is how it relates to truth. That's exactly the underlying idea with dogma, necessity of belief and heresy as sin. Where you differ is that you define truth in relation to salvation when it is only the other way. Salvation is Truth but Truth is not only Salvation. "If a definitive teaching adds nothing to the intrinsic value of salvation then there is no ground to require belief" sure there is. If it is true, you should belief it.

Comment: @MikeBorden "salvation of you is the same if Mary is not a perpetual virgin" again, I l have raised that point to you on the other question (i.e. I don't disagree). Your questions are predicated on assuming that doctrinal truth only has value because it affects salvation (presumably in the sense of outlining our obligations or highlighting God's means) but that's an assumption which not everyone holds.

Comment: @eques You left off the critical end of the sentence:  "...no ground to require belief in that teaching *as necessary for salvation*".  Not all truth is equal.  Believing that Jesus is the Son of the Living God who died to save sinners is not the same as believing my wife is faithful to me.  Both are true and should be believed but both are not salvatory; plenty of atheists have faithful wives and plenty of saved folk have unfaithful partners.  Marian Dogmas are made salvatory when denial renders one lost.

Comment: @eques  "You don't disagree with this: "salvation of you is the same if Mary is not a perpetual virgin" but you also don't disagree with this: "rejecting the perpetual virginity of Mary renders one lost".  If one is lost by rejecting something then one cannot be saved without accepting that something.  An enormous number of 'somethings' are tacked on to "Believe on the Lord Jesus Christ and you shall be saved".   Did the Philippian jailer need to accept the Marion Dogmas or else be lost?

Comment: @MikeBorden No, I did not leave off that sentence. Kindly try to understand what I'm saying instead of reading in what you want to hear. There is a distinction you keep dancing around; you continue to insist that obligation for belief only relates to what effects salvation hence any other category of truth is at best a matter of free opinion. This may be your view but it is not the Catholic view, so if you assume that, you will find absurdities when you try to ask about Catholic understanding.

Comment: @MikeBorden "If one is lost by rejecting something then one cannot be saved without accepting that something" Sorta, but not quite the distinction I am making. It is not that Marian dogmas save you, nor for that matter that Trinitarian dogmas save you. It is because God has revealed those truths through His Church "the pillar and ground of the truth", (2 Tim 3:15) you better accept them. "He that heareth you, heareth me" (Luke 10:16)

Comment: The other key distinction you are overlooking is the voluntary nature. A soul who doesn't know about the perpetual virginity and so has never had cause to reject it could be saved and their salvation wouldn't be more or less than someone who positively knew about the perpetual virginity and accepted it. A soul who knew about it and rejected it would not attain to salvation insofar as that rejection was a willful act against revealed truth.

Comment: @eques We are obliged and best served to believe all things that are true but not all things are salvatory.  I'm not dancing around a distinction but highlighting one to show that belief in Marion Dogma has been made salvatory alongside faith in Christ.  For example, someone hears the gospel, repents, calls on the name of the Lord, and is saved.  Years later that someone has the Marion dogmas explained and rejects them as a result of honest bible study and prayer.  Your proposition is that this person has lost the salvation purchased and provided and accessed through Christ alone.

Comment: @eques If this person wishes to return to a good standing before the Lord it is now not a matter of returning to faith in Christ (which was never abandoned) but placing faith in somebody else also, and not even somebody else really but something about somebody else; something which is freely admitted to add nothing to the salvation Christ has affected but is enforced as though it is critical.   You say it is not Marion Dogmas that save but the Catholic Church says if you reject them you are lost so...you can't be saved by Christ unless you are either ignorant of them or believe them.

Comment: @eques And if you believe them your salvation in Christ is not enhanced, bettered, or perfected in any way.  Maybe you're trying to get me to see something that mitigates all this but I honestly don't see it, whatever it is.

Comment: So we are obliged, but if we don't oblige, no penalty? Most of the rest of what you say gets close to the heart of Protestantism vs Catholicism, so as I said before if you make Protestant assumptions, you will conclude absurdities about Catholic doctrine. If you make room for Catholic assumptions, things will fall more into place even if you don't accept the basic premises.

Comment: Of course salvation isn't bettered. You don't get to experience more heaven because of Marian or Trinitarian dogma, but the depth of the wonders of God is more revealed. No, Marian dogmas aren't salutary; that's a sloppy misuse of terms. Marian dogmas are no more salutary by being believed than belief in moral truths are (you aren't saved by believing murder is sinful). In Catholicism, sinners are shut out of heaven whether they sin in thought, word or deed, which includes heresy; that is the willful rejection or obstinate denial of revealed truth.

Comment: @eques There are always consequences when belief doesn't align with truth both in the physical and the spiritual realms.  I think we agree that not all truth is salvific (apparently salvatory is the wrong word).  As you say, one is not saved by believing Marion Dogma but one is excluded from salvation or loses salvation through rejection of it,  which  makes those truths salvific in a practical sense for Catholicism.

Comment: @eques In Protestantism (for the most part) it is not doctrine that saves but a person and the work that He has done.  Trusting completely in that person's work saves because no other work has merit (everyone else has sinned) and this opens one up to be conformed to truth.  For most Protestants, being conformed to truth is a process of sanctification which is the product of salvation not the means.

Comment: @eques A Protestant could (theoretically) reach the accurate acceptance of  all truth and perfectly think, speak, and do in accordance with that truth but still only be saved by the work of that one person.  We are not afraid that our failures in belief or life could undo what our savior has done but, instead, we trust that He will get us there in spite of our failures.  I see the distinction now ... by grace through faith unto works vs. by grace through faith and works.  Thank you.

Comment: @MikeBorden I don't see how *any* of that is relevant to the discussion above. While Catholics and Protestants do differ in their understandings of faith vs works, the Protestant view of the Catholic is generally imprecise at best. That said, rejecting doctrine is an act just like speaking blasphemy, lying, adultery and murder. The sinful will not inherit eternal life.

Comment: "which makes those truths salvific in a practical sense for Catholicism" No, it doesn't. Salvific means causes salvation. Belief in Marian dogmas no more causes salvation than avoiding sin on its own does.

Comment: @eques As it stands right now according to Catholicism (if I'm understanding it correctly) I **cannot be saved unless** I believe that Mary never had sexual relations with a man either before (accepted) or after Jesus was born.   If I cannot be saved unless "A" how is "A", therefore, not salvific as in necessary for salvation?

Comment: You also cannot be saved if you commit murder and don't repent. Is not committing murder salvific?

Comment: @eques First, it seems you are equating the commission of murder with the rejection of Mary's perpetual virginity.  One need not appeal to the halls of tradition to establish the wrongness of murder yet one cannot find the latter anywhere else.  Second, only one thing under heaven is salvific and that is the name of the Lord Jesus Christ.  One's behavior neither loses nor gains salvation, it merely demonstrates one's condition.

Comment: @MikeBorden Insofar as they are both acts which when done willfully they would be sinful in the same category, yes. However, heresy and murder are not equal in gravity. The point is that both result in a loss of salvation. "only one thing under heaven is salvific" That is not the issue. Try to understand instead of repeating Protestant platitudes. No Catholic believes Mary is salvific. That is at best a Protestant misunderstanding and at worse a lie.

Comment: @eques To believe that a saved person could commit murder and not repent is to hold to a form of godliness but deny the power of it.  Didn't God send Nathan to bring about David's repentance?  Who, then, gets credit for the repentance?  Salvation is of the Lord from first to last.

Comment: @MikeBorden I don't get what your point is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142585/discussion-between-mike-borden-and-eques).

Answer (score 1):

I think you misunderstand the second answer: *Even without the perpetual virginity of Mary, our salvation in Christ not lessened!* It is referring to the hypothetical case that if it didn't happen at all, it wouldn't have affected the salvation. They are saying, maybe, it wasn't necessary for salvation (this must be a fringe opinion of a liberal catholic, you can ignore it anyway). This doesn't say, "without our belief in that, our salvation in Christ is not lessened.

The Marian dogmas are central to the Roman Catholic Church, it is uncompromisable. I don't think the best Catholic view would allow that it was even possible for Mary to have a marital relation, in other words, the second answer is not representative of the Catholic faith. You cannot have Christ and salvation without the Queen of heaven, Mother of God. Rejecting basic dogmas about her is equal to denying dogmas about Jesus.

Even the assumption of Mary, regarding her ascension to heaven is an uncompromisable belief. The doctrine of original sin was postulated to exempt Jesus, and make him separate from mankind. Similarly, it is necessary to exempt Mary from the same human nature, which could be tainted by her sexual relation if her immaculate virgin state is tainted. As, it can be assumed that original sin passes or is contracted by natural human sex and birth.

From this catholic page on [the assumption](https://www.newadvent.org/cathen/02006b.htm):

> Note: By promulgating the Bull Munificentissimus Deus, 1 November, 1950, Pope Pius XII declared infallibly that the Assumption of the Blessed Virgin Mary was a dogma of the Catholic Faith. Likewise, the Second Vatican Council taught in the Dogmatic Constitution Lumen Gentium that "the Immaculate Virgin, preserved free from all stain of original sin, was taken up body and soul into heavenly glory, when her earthly life was over, and exalted by the Lord as Queen over all things (n. 59)."

It can be postulated that rejecting the immaculate and separate nature of Mary, would also lead eventually rejecting the virgin birth of Jesus, in a slippery slope of logic. The assumptions of her nature are created only to justify the separated nature of Jesus.

Comment: I'm not sure if Ken Graham (who provided that answer) is a liberal Catholic espousing fringe positions or not.  I also have had a conversation with Peter Turner where he also stated that the perpetual virginity of Mary adds nothing to our salvation in Christ.  If sin is passed paternally (which is why a virgin needed to conceive in the first place) the difficulty vanishes.  The sin nature is not inherited through the mother and so all the assumptions of her nature that were created are not actually necessary.

Comment: those are all debatable issues. I am sure it is a necessary belief in Catholic faith, you should just read their official site and sources. As for original sin and its transmission, I reject them altogether as unnecessary.

Comment: Yikes!  You don't think we are born with a sin nature or you don't favor the Catholic definition of original sin?

Comment: Neither. I reject Catholic doctrine of original sin altogether. I believe Paul and other apostles would have rejected it as well. https://web.archive.org/web/20210217221849/https://www.gospeltruth.net/OS100bibleverses.htm

Comment: If you reject original sin and it's transmission, how can you provide a truly Catholic response to this subject matter!  Original sin is dogma held by the Catholic Church. This answer is totally unorthodox to Catholic understanding of what the Church professes.

Comment: Ken, one doesn't have to be a catholic to provide answers about catholic religion. I can provide great deal of answers about Islam as well.

Comment: True you do not have to be Catholic to answer Catholic questions, but the post should reflect Catholic thought.

Comment: While this answer touches on the specifics of Marian dogmas, the underlying context is broader. Marian dogmas are the primary stumbling block for Protestants, but they aren't special as far as the obligation to believe

Answer (score 1):

To be able to address the stated question (and the implied question), we must first lay out some underlying premises.

First, according to Catholic doctrine any soul who dies with an unrepentant mortal sin upon their soul will be condemned to hell (hence will not be saved). This appears to be equivalent to what the OP means by "losing salvation"

Second, any mortal sin (a sin done with complete knowledge and consent and involving grave matter) is sufficient; the necessity of belief in Marian dogmas isn't special in this regard. It applies equally to murder, adultery, fornication, theft, blasphemy, drunkenness, or any other grave evil.

Third, rejecting belief in dogma either by refusing assent or actively believing something contrary is a species of heresy. As addressed in [Why is Heresy a Mortal Sin](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/94349/in-catholicism-why-is-heresy-a-mortal-sin), heresy is a grave sin because it is an offense against the virtue of faith which orients the intellect towards things beyond natural reason and heresy is a willful aversion from God because "by false knowledge of God, man does not approach Him, but is severed from Him" (cf. [Summa Theologica II-II q. 10 a. 3](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS010.html#SSQ10A3THEP1) quoted on linked question). Furthermore, "no one draws near to God except by faith, because faith is a light of the intellect.... anyone drawing near by faith must believe the Lord" (cf [Commentary on Hebrews C11 L2](https://aquinas.cc/la/en/%7EHeb.C11.L2.n575.2), quoted in linked question).

To sum, a willful rejection of revealed dogmatic truth (whether Marian or otherwise) would constitute mortal sin which if one does not repent of that sin before death, one would be condemned to hell.

> In other words, any member of any Protestant denomination or Church whatsoever who has what the RCC considers to be valid baptism and marriage sacraments are still completely and hopelessly lost if they knowingly and deliberately reject say, the 'Perpetual Virginity of Mary' for example

Not necessarily or at least we need some further qualifications. The statements above hold clearly for Catholics  insofar as they are members of the Church both sacramentally and canonically, that is, the recognize the authority of the Church. Protestants (more specifically anyone validly baptized yet not in formal communion) are members of the Church (broadly speaking) yet not canonically part of the "commonwealth" of the Church. The question then becomes to what extent someone who doesn't formally recognize the authority of the Catholic Church is bound to believe what the Church has declared necessary to be believed. This in turn depends on what their reasons are for not belonging to the Catholic Church. If they remain outside the Catholic Church due to no fault of their own, they wouldn't be held accountable for not accepting the authority of the Church for the necessity of those dogmas. However, if they remain outside the Catholic Church because they refuse to join despite some knowledge that it is the Church established by Christ or obstinately refuse to consider its claims, etc, then that refusal to accept the authority becomes voluntary in a sense.

> but it seems a contradiction to declare that a person will be lost unless they believe a doctrine that has no salvific benefit

The assumption is that only things that have salvific benefits must be believed. What though is a salvific benefit or what does it mean that a doctrine has salvific benefit? This could be understood different ways potentially.

One way is narrower in the sense of doctrines which describe some aspect of how salvation occurred and thus perhaps they are necessary to believe because they are necessary for salvation to be possible. An example of a doctrine in this category might be the virgin birth or the death on the cross. The question would be why must I believe specific things about how God accomplished salvation -- is my knowledge of them required for him to save me? The problem with this is twofold: one, in that it seems to make belief of instrumental value (I only need to belief what accomplishes salvation for me -- what is in it for me?) and two, it orders all theological truth to Salvation. While Aquinas does teach that at least in some respects justification is a greater work than creation, he would point out that creation is first in the divine plan; that is God didn't create a world so that he had someone to save. God created a world, which needed to saved after creation.

The other way would be broader and as a result looser or rather it only analogously has a salvific benefit because it's not belief in the thing itself which saves but God that saves, but rejection of what God has revealed (as related above) would be sinful and cut a soul off from the life of grace and salvation. More precisely, it is not explicitly a Catholic dogma that belief is only necessary on things that have a salvific benefit per se -- it might be a view espoused by some Protestant denominations perhaps.

> Perhaps for a Roman Catholic the perpetual virginity of Mary adds a depth of understanding to the entire plan of salvation, the nature of God, etc., and that is fine

In the specific case of the Marian dogmas (Perpetual Virginity among the rest), the dogmas were formulated to safeguard Christological dogmas. That is, Marian doctrine tends to develop to highlight and safeguard doctrines around Christ and his salvific work. The perpetual virginity for example was declared amidst the early controversies on the Personhood of Christ -- i.e. in what way is Christ human or divine?

Comment: "if they remain outside the Catholic Church because they refuse to join despite some knowledge that it is the Church established by Christ" It's not. The Roman Catholics schismed from Orthodoxy, which was the original Church established by Paul and the Apostles, not the other way around.

Comment: @nick012000 Doctrinal debates are off-topic here, so your comment is not relevant here. The question is tagged Catholicism, not Orthodoxy. This is an answer from the perspective of Catholicism and Catholicism as it has always sees Orthodox as splitting away.